# How to count the amount of tuples who don't change in a specific value range in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, rows, percentage

I work with folowing tables:
[ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb1b79/1]

table companies:

```
| ID | CNAME | COUNTRY | CLASS |
|----|-------|---------|-------|
|  1 |   ABC |  Russia |     A |
|  2 |   DEF |  Russia |     B |
```

table vals:

```
| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | YEAR |
|----|--------|--------|------|
|  1 |    100 |     20 | 2005 |
|  1 |    200 |     40 | 2006 |
|  1 |    400 |     81 | 2007 |
|  1 |    101 |     16 | 2008 |
|  2 |    300 |     22 | 1999 |
|  2 |    900 |     30 | 2001 |
|  2 |    600 |     10 | 2002 |
```

What i am trying to do is:

- calculate value1/value2 for each company and year, then count the **amount** of companies for each country and class, who **don't** change between the next given year more than 2%.
- the calculated **amount** should be given,  the percentage to all companies in this country (percentage1) and to all companies in this country/class (percentage2).

the result should be:

```
| COUNTRY | CLASS | AMOUNT | PERCENTAGE1 | PERCENTAGE2 |
|---------|-------|--------|-------------|-------------|
|  Russia |     A |      3 |        0.75 |       0.428 |
|  Russia |     B |      0 |           0 |       0.428 |
```

Can anyone give me an approach?

Comment: What is the rule to derive the percentage? Is it `value1/value2` value for each year? I can answer your question, but the percentage part is not clear. Can you explain more. For example, `value1/value2` for ID 1 in year 2005 is `100/20` i.e. `5`, next year the value is `200/40` again `5`, so no change at all.

Comment: you are absolutely right. so the change between 2005 and 2006 is 0% and between 2006 and 2007 is 1.23% (2006 value1/value2=5 and 2007 value1/value2=4.938) so between this years the change would in the 2% range and should be counted.

Answer (score 0):

A LAG() or LEAD() analytic function would get you previous/next year's values for a direct comparison of "this year versus last year", or you could do the same with a join based on "a.year = b.year - 1". I'd benchmark both in order to see which will work best for your data volumes and distribution.

That will then allow you to apply a CASE statement to categorise the ranges of value change as being less than or more than 2%.

Then you can aggregate the data based on that categorisation to get the values you need -- a Ratio_to_Report analytic function might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Analytic **LEAD** function. The rest is simple mathematics and calculations.

To get the change in percentage for `VALUE1/VALUE2` for each **ID** based on the **YEAR**, you could do:

`lead(val) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, YEAR)`

where **VAL** is `VALUE1/VALUE2`.

Let's look at a test case:

**Set up**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM companies;

        ID CNA COUNTR C
---------- --- ------ -
         1 ABC Russia A
         2 DEF Russia B

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM vals;

        ID     VALUE1     VALUE2       YEAR
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100         20       2005
         1        200         40       2006
         1        400         81       2007
         1        101         16       2008
         2        300         22       1999
         2        900         30       2001
         2        600         10       2002

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, Implementing the above logic would give us:

```
SQL> WITH data1 AS
  2    ( SELECT t.*, ROUND(value1/value2, 2) val FROM vals t ORDER BY YEAR
  3    ),
  4    data2 AS
  5    (SELECT t.*,
  6      lead(val) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, YEAR) prev
  7    FROM data1 t
  8    )
  9  SELECT t.*, ROUND(((val - prev)/val)* 100, 2) percentage FROM data2 t;

        ID     VALUE1     VALUE2       YEAR        VAL       PREV PERCENTAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100         20       2005          5          5          0
         1        200         40       2006          5       4.94        1.2
         1        400         81       2007       4.94       6.31     -27.73
         1        101         16       2008       6.31
         2        300         22       1999      13.64         30    -119.94
         2        900         30       2001         30         60       -100
         2        600         10       2002         60

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your words *"between 2006 and 2007 is 1.23% (2006 value1/value2=5 and 2007 value1/value2=4.938)"* I concluded, 
that formula for yearly change is `1 - current (v1/v2)/previous (v1/v2)`. Also it seems, that rows with unknown previous values
should not be included in further calculations. If this is not so, please remove filter `where lvv is not null`.

All rows where value1 or value2 is equal to 0 should probably be removed, because in current or next steps they can produce 
dividing by zero, but I did not filtered them here as I am not sure what do you want to do in such situation. 
And it's not quite clear what do you mean by *"who don't change between the next given year more than 2%"*. 
I used condition `abs(1-vv/lvv) <= .02` for that, but you may want to change it to `1-vv/lvv < .02` for instance.

The final result is different from yours, I suspect you just showed how result should look like (for instance last value in percentage2 is 0.428 and amount is 0 - this is inconsistent).
If this is not what you wanted please edit your post, add some more examples and desired output which match input, this way we can verify something :-)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46688/1)

```
with 
step1 as (select id, year, cname, country, class, round(value1/value2, 8) vv, 
    round(lag(value1/value2) over (partition by id order by year), 8) lvv
  from vals v join companies c using (id) where value2<>0 ),
step2 as (select step1.*, round(1-vv/lvv, 8) change_value,
    case when abs(1-vv/lvv) <= .02 then 1 end as change,
    count(1) over (partition by country) cc,
    count(1) over (partition by country, class) ccc
  from step1 where lvv is not null )
select country, class, count(change) amount, 
    round(count(change) / max(cc), 4) percentage1,
    round(count(change) / max(ccc), 4) percentage2
  from step2 group by country, class order by country, class
```

Output (I added some companies from other coutries):

```
COUNTRY  CLASS  AMOUNT  PERCENTAGE1  PERCENTAGE2
-------  -----  ------  -----------  -----------
Brazil   A           1            1            1
Canada   A           1         0,25          0,5
Canada   B           2          0,5            1
Russia   A           2          0,4       0,6667
Russia   B           0            0            0
```